# How to get minecraft-pi up and running on a Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, minecraft

I try to have some fun with minecraft-pi on a raspberry 4, but I can't get it to work.

- first I managed to get it up and running on a plain system (latest raspbian), but it wasn't running in a window and I couldn't exit it nor could I switch back to another window (tried tab, alt-tab, alt-f4 etc)
- then I read switched the monitor resolution (fonts where too small on a 4K display). The result was that mincecraft-pi din't run anymore. A black window popped up for a fraction of a second and that's it. When I started it from the shell, I got a cryptic error message which I tried to google - without any success)
- I then found a hint to deactivate the GL drivers. Now I get a black window but now minecraft window.

and yes, I also removed minecrapt-pi and re-installed it without success...

Any idea what is going wrong?

PS: error message was

```
Error of failed request: BadValue (Integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcide of failed request: 153 (XFree86-VidModeExtension)
Minor opcode of failed request: 10 (XF86VidModeSwitchToMode)
Value in failed request: 0x380
Serial number of failed request: 137
Current serial number in output stream: 139
```

Update: `apt update`& `apt upgrade` tell me that everything is up to date. In addition, if I put the sd card into a raspi 3, everything works like a charm.

Comment: I exactly had this problem before updating the GL drivers. Make sure you have the latest patches installed (run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`), and then it should run with GL drivers active. Hint: To get the mouse control back, hit ESC.

Comment: thanx @PMF - I just gave it a try. Both, update and upgrade tell me that everything is up to date. I now also tried to put my sd card into a pi 3 - works like a charm. Maybe I have to switch devices...

Answer (score 2):

Have you switched screen resolution?

I get the exact SAME error if I don't play on the default resolution settings.